# how to insert into google sheets data by named range using php api?

Tags: php, google-sheets

Tell me about this issue, I can’t find it in the documentation. Is it possible to insert into a table by column names. For example, there are columns name, price, quantity, and you only need to insert the name and quantity. Using a method like this

```
$values = [
    ["Samsung", "10"],
];

$ValueRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();

$ValueRange->setValues($values);

$options = ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'];

$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $list . '!A' . $total, $ValueRange, $options);
```

The number of 10 should be inserted in the B column where the price is located. quantity in column C

Is it possible to somehow insert data by column names? Maybe some examples in php?

Comment: there is no out-of-the-box solution. First you need to read the header row, then use your code to prepare cells data and finally save the values using the Sheets API

Comment: Can't you transfer the range of cells along with the values? For example range = ['a1', 'c1'] $values = [
    ["Samsung", "10"],
];

Comment: check the Sheets API, it is well documented